# Why is my Samsung Galaxy phone automatically moving read Yahoo email to the spam folder?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2

Why is my Samsung Galaxy phone automatically moving read Yahoo email to the spam folder? This usually happens when there is an attachment.

Comment: What email client are you using? The stock Samsung one, Yahoo's own, or something else? And which Samsung Galaxy phone do you have?

Answer (score 0):

This is another post that I found on this.  Basically the Samsung phone has it's own spam settings.  http://www.slipstick.com/outlook/moves-email-junk-folder/ describes this, and then explains:

> **The solution:**
>
> 1. Go into the E-Mail app (on the phone)
> 2. Press the Menu Key, select Settings, then General Settings
> 3. Select Spam addresses and remove any addresses that should not be in there, such as your corporate domain.

Comment: Welcome to the Android Enthusiasts! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Otherwise, your answer becomes useless in case the link dies. For further hints, please see: [How do I write a good answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).